# Invalid Syntax in lambda function - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda

I am trying to impute missing values in a column known as own_house_age.

Pardon me for not being able to see this but what's invalid about this syntax?

```
own_house_impute = lambda x: (x['Own_House_Age'].replace(np.nan, value = 0)) if (x['House_Own'] == 0)
                        else (x['Own_House_Age'].replace(np.nan, value = np.median(df['Own_house_Age'])))
```

And this is the error that I get

```
File "<ipython-input-15-58ac93fedced>", line 1
    own_house_impute = lambda x: (x['Own_House_Age'].replace(np.nan, value = 0)) if (x['House_Own'] == 0)
                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And this is how to two relevant columns look like

```
House_Own   |    Own_House_Age
--------------------------------- 
            |       
   0.0      |        NaN
   0.0      |        NaN
   0.0      |        Nan
   1.0      |        4.0
   1.0      |        Nan
```

Comment: A parenthesis should be around the whole if-else and/or lambda function

Comment: @Vishnudev tried doing that, not working.

Comment: Please provide some sample data as input and expected output in the question @Sachin

Comment: Try this `own_house_impute = (lambda x: x['Own_House_Age'].replace(np.nan, value = 0) if x['House_Own'] == 0 else x['Own_House_Age'].replace(np.nan, value = np.median(df['Own_house_Age'])))`

Comment: @Vishnudev This works to eliminate the invalid syntax error but now it says that float object isn't subscriptable. I've also included sample data for your reference.

Comment: Attach the traceback @Sachin

Comment: How are you trying to use `own_house_impute`?

Comment: @piterbarg Using it as a custom function to impute missing values based on certain filter conditions.

Comment: I would be useful if you added a piece of code that actually calls it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
df['Own_House_Age'] = np.where(df.House_Own == 0, 0, np.median(df.House_Own))
```

Comment: For some reason,  the percentage of missing values increased from 65 to 70 with this method. Nevermind, I've figured out to simpler method to deal with this. Imputing all the values with zero itself.